# How to write routes right in Ruby-on-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `routes.rb` file, I have the following code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'getTodos', to: 'todos#get'
  get 'getUsers', to: 'users#get'
  get 'getStates', to: 'states#get'

  post 'addTodo', to: 'todos#add'
  post 'addUser', to: 'users#add'

  delete 'deleteTodo/*id', to: 'todos#delete'
  delete 'deleteUsers/*IDs', to: 'users#delete'
  delete 'deleteAllTodos', to: 'todos#delete_all'

  put 'updateTodo', to: 'todos#update'
end
```

How can I modify this code to make it more beautiful and correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue with this code is that its completely unidiomatic. In Rails you create, read, update and destroy (CRUD) resources through the following routes:

```
HTTP Method   Path                       Controller#Action
GET           /todos(.:format)           todos#index
POST          /todos(.:format)           todos#create
GET           /todos/new(.:format)       todos#new
GET           /todos/:id/edit(.:format)  todos#edit                                                              GET           /todos/:id(.:format)       todos#show
PATCH         /todos/:id(.:format)       todos#update
PUT           /todos/:id(.:format)       todos#update
DELETE        /todos/:id(.:format)       todos#destroy
```

The key here is the combination of the HTTP method and path.

- `GET /todos` gets you all the todos while `GET /todos/:id` shows you a specific resource.
- `GET /todos/new` displays the form to create a new todo. `POST /todos` actually creates the resource from a form submission.
- `GET /todos/:id/edit` displays the form to edit a todo. `PATCH /todos/:id` actually updates the resource from a form submission.
- `DELETE /todos/:id` - You should be able to guess what this does.

You can generate these routes with:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos
end
```

If you want to define a routes that deletes all the todos RESTfully it should be defined as `DELETE /todos` (without an id).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos do
    delete '/', on: :collection, action: :destroy_all
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

See:

- [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Try to use default Rails REST actions instead of overwriting them

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy] do
    collection do
      delete :delete_all, to: 'todos#delete_all'
    end
  end
  resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
  resources :states, only: :index
```